# error when converting Pageable to List in Java

Tags: java

I have programmed to return a product page. And it worked well

Here is an example:

**productServiceImpl.java**

```
public Page<ProductDTO> findProduct(Pageable pageable) {

   Page<ProductDTO> page = this.repository.findProduct(pageable);
           
   return page;
       
}
```

**produtoRepositoryImpl.java**

```
        public Page<ProductDTO> obterProdutoFilho(Pageable pageable) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("     SELECT DISTINCT P.ID  ");
        sb.append("                   , P.NAME  ");
        sb.append("                   , C.ID AS PRODUCT_ID  ");

        sb.append("     FROM  ");
        sb.append("                     {database_user}.PRODUCT_A P,   ");
        sb.append("                     {database_user}.PRODUCT_B C   ");
        sb.append("     WHERE   ");
        sb.append("                      P.ID = C.product_r_ID  ");


        Map<String, Type> mapFields = new HashMap<>();
        mapFields.put("id", StandardBasicTypes.LONG);
        mapFields.put("name", StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
        mapFields.put("product_id", StandardBasicTypes.LONG);

        Map<String, Object> mapParams = new HashMap<>();

        Page<ProductDTO> page = super.page(this.em, sb, pageable, mapParams, mapFields, true, ProductDTO.class);

        return page;
    }
```

When trying to convert to a list, I get an error.

***java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.domain.Page***

I tried to cast this way.

```
    @Override
    public Page<ProductDTO> findProduct(Pageable pageable) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Page<ProductDTO> page = (Page<ProductDTO>) this.repository.findProduct(pageable).getContent();

        return page;
    }
```

thank you since now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This return Page object:

```
this.repository.findProduct(pageable)
```

And this return List object:

```
this.repository.findProduct(pageable).getContent()
```

Then this should work (assuming that you want to return the list in your method):

```
public List<ProductDTO> findProduct(Pageable pageable) {
    return this.repository.findProduct(pageable).getContent();
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. But will it return only the first 20 items on my page or can I list everything?

Comment: just the first 20 items